# Lync UserEndpoint appears online to users but can't be called

Tags: c#, lync-2013, ucma

I have a Lync 2013-based application which:

1. connects to a UserEndpoint (hereinafter CallCenter)
   redirects calls made to CallCenter according to bla bla bla business logic.
2. At times, a user will see CallCenter in their standard Lync 2013 Client as Online, but if that user attempts to start an IM call with CallCenter, the user receives the message "We couldn't send this message because CallCenter is unavailable or offline."

I haven't been able to identify the process that leads up to this, but if it's happened to one user, then all of the other users experience the same problem when attempting to call CallCenter. The only way I have been able to recover CallCenter has been to restart my application. Regular interaction with CallCenter then resumes without a problem.

If CallCenter is indeed "unavailable or offline", then why does it's Presence appear as "Online"? Is there a need to renew / keep CallCenter's connection alive every so often?

For reference, I connect CallCenter like so:

```
UserEndpointSettings settings = new UserEndpointSettings(userURI, _ProxyHost, _ProxyPort);
settings.AutomaticPresencePublicationEnabled = true;
settings.Presence.UserPresenceState = PresenceState.UserAvailable;

_userEndpoint = new UserEndpoint(_Platform.CollabPlatform, settings);
_userEndpoint.BeginEstablish(res =>
{
    try
    {
        _userEndpoint.EndEstablish(res);
        _userEndpoint.StateChanged += new EventHandler<LocalEndpointStateChangedEventArgs>(_userEndpoint_StateChanged);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(ex, ErrorReference.EndpointEstablishFailed);
    }
}, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the client, when you go offline or experience an error, your presence reflects that (most of the time, that is). This can lead you to believe that the status portion of presence [1] is somehow tied to actual availability.

When you're working with UCMA, you are given ultimate control over everything related to your endpoint. As you've seen, you can make your UCMA application do things that would otherwise be impossible in the regular client.  You don't have to publish *any* presence status (leaving you "offline" to your users), yet the service can still send/receive IMs. And, as you've seen, your service can be "Available" and yet ... have no capability to do anything *but* publish its status [2].

If you fail to wire up the appropriate modality (in your case IM), or your application encounters an exception which results in a particular modality no longer working (I suspect this may be your actual problem), the status of your service will still be *available*.

Begin/EndTerminate on the UserEndpoint should publish Offline for you automatically and publishing a presence other than Available is the only way to guarantee the presence won't be "Available" for the lifetime of your application (and even after the application ends/dies prematurely, though this is sometimes rectified by the server -- *sometimes*).

Here's how I'd attack resolving this issue. Ignore the presence problem and ignore the error. They're red herrings. Many problems result in the "unavailable or offline" message that have nothing to do with the service actually being stopped.

Instead, figure out why your calls aren't connecting.

If the call takes a while before you receive the error, check for deadlocks or circumstances where the Thread Pool has no room for another thread. Troubleshooting involves reviewing your code for race conditions and the myriad of other things that multi-threaded applications throw your way.  If the IMCall fails instantly, check around the parts that handle incoming calls. In the latter case, your subscription may be gone (too many causes to list here, most of which are .Net related, not UCMA related), or your service may be dead.

If the importance of presence to your application is only to show it as "available" or "offline" when it is actually able to send/receive an IM, you're going to want to ensure your application terminates the endpoint properly during tear-down (including in the case of a critical failure: catch-terminate-rethrow or whatever is appropriate in your case).

[1] Be careful when thinking about the term "presence" as it relates to Lync. Presence contains availability status, modality specific states, capabilities (IM/Voice, etc), the "note" and contact information.

[2] This seems like a bizarre thing to do, however, it gave me the ability to use an ApplicationEndpoint to report on the availability of a web service (unrelated to Lync) that I wanted to be able to view in the Mobile client without connecting via VPN. When doing something like this, it's really important to publish the capabilities of your endpoint -- this will explicitly signal to your connected clients what your service can and cannot do.

[Final Footnote] There are a few ways to publish presence. The mechanism you're using to publish is the simplest and most logical to use if you're just interested in telling your users that the "service is here"/"service is not here" which is documented rather well here: [Simplified Presence Publication for Endpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh364887%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Beautiful answer! It turns out that at times, the CallCenter would get disconnected (for a reason currently being debugged directly with Microsoft) and during the rewiring process, the listener for IncomingCalls was not rewired. Ergo, I could see the user's presence as Online, but it wasn't able to receive incoming calls.